# Plot a graph of node energy from NS2 Trace file (.tr file)

Tags: networking, network-programming, tcl, simulation, ns2

I am trying to plot a graph of node energy versus time by giving some initial energy using trace file.
How do we put the energy parameters in trace file(.tr) in ns2? What is the syntax used in record function in .tcl file?

Comment: Did u find a solution? If yes, let me knw please.

Answer (score 0):

use the below awk script to find the energy of node

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
#print "energy of node 1"
data=0
}

{
if ($1=="N" && $5==0)
{
    print $3,$7
}
}
END{
#print "Completed"
}
```

save this file as energy.awk

in terminal type

```
$gawk -f energy.awk "yourtracefile.tr" > node0.dat
```

on executing this command you'll get a file node0.dat

in terminal

```
$xgraph -P node0.dat
```

you'll get a graph